# select part of a file name with regex

Tags: regex-group

i have a file u01/appl/wandl/import/AT/file.csv. i need to get the AT part only and store it in a variable using regex.it is always a 2 digit code but it could  be BE UK etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/([A-Z]{2})\/
```

That regex find exactly two big letters with / / around so it finds things like /AT/ or /UK/ or /BE/ 
As you can see parentheses are around 2 digit code so only code will be captures by grouping

Comment: thanks thats cool, just one thing I have one entry named AORTA in the same position is it possible to extend the 2 characters to also include 5

Comment: the output of this is /UK/ . i just need UK